# Installing 9.1 XP0 - Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, identity-server

After installing 9.1 I see the following error on the login screen:

[image: Error Message]

Steps I followed:

1. Updated XP0-SingleDeveloper with ".dev.sc.local" to the site names
2. Ran the installation using XP0-SingleDeveloper.ps1 and SIF 2.0
3. Updated IIS host binding to use https for "sc910.dev.sc.local".

### Update

While setting up a new 10.2 instance I encountered the error "invalid_request". This was caused by the `AllowedCorsOrigins` not containing the correct url. The log messages in Identity showed something like the following:

> Invalid redirect_uri: "https://scmsx.int.sxp.local/identity/signin"

Turns out I mistakenly put the wrong url in the `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <IdentityServer>          
      <Clients>
        <DefaultClient>
          <AllowedCorsOrigins>
            <!-- This should show scmsx instead of identityx -->
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>https://identityx.int.sxp.local</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
          </AllowedCorsOrigins>
        </DefaultClient>
      </Clients>
    </IdentityServer>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

After speaking with my friend @kamsar, he pointed out the CORS origin on the Identity Server Instance needs an update.

The Identity Server doesn't allow logging in from just any url, for security reasons.

- Open the file `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc910.identityserver.dev.sc.local\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml`
- Add a new *AllowedCorsOriginsGroupN* (optionally use a pipe delimiter pointed out by @monkey-dsc)
- Recycle the Identity Server Application Pool

Below you can see the new setting added as Group2:

```
<AllowedCorsOrigins>
  <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>http://sc910.dev.sc.local</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
  <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>https://sc910.dev.sc.local</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>
</AllowedCorsOrigins>
```

### Resources

- [Found this link to the 9.1 documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/configure-a-sitecore-instance-and-sitecore-identity-server.html)
- [Configuration patching for Sitecore Host](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/configuration.html)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Michaels correct answer: 
It is also possible to define the AllowedCorsOrigins pipe-separated. 
I also stuck on this and found the description in the IdentityServer WDP zip (parameters.xml):

```
    <parameter name="AllowedCorsOrigins" description="Pipe-separated list of instances (URIs) that are allowed to login via Sitecore Identity.">
      <parameterEntry kind="TextFile" scope="website\\config\\production\\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host\.xml" match="PlaceholderForClientOriginsGroup" />
    </parameter>
```

You can define the Origins like that:

```
      <AllowedCorsOrigins>
        <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>http://sc910.dev.sc.local|https://sc910.dev.sc.local</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1>
        <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>http://otherhost.dev.sc.local|https://otherhost.dev.sc.local</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>
      </AllowedCorsOrigins>
```

Comment: I see value in using the pipe delimiter in order to make these entries match those from sxa tenants.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to apply this as a patch? Something that can be dropped into a folder?

Comment: unfortunately not :( it is set by the XP0-Single-Developer.ps1 --> $AllowedCorsOrigins = "http://$SitecoreSiteName"... maybe you can adjust the script to have more $SitecoreSiteNames

Answer (score 6):

I tried using https instead of http to access my local sitecore admin panel like this

https://site.local/sitecore and it worked remember every request in sitecore 9.1 needs to be in secure SSL so use only https ! Hope it helps someone.

Comment: It helped me. I tried with https and it worked for me. Thanks