# Unable to open the Business tools from launchpad

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I Have installed Sitecore 9.1 commerce. When I try to open Business tools from launchpad i'm facing the below error

"Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client

[image]

Why this happened ?

Comment: There's no way for us to tell, without knowing your installation setup and seeing the log files (an exception would have been logged).

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/15529/95 this may be the solution.