# Configuration patching not working in Identity Server

Tags: identity-server, patch-configuration, sitecore-managed-cloud

I am working on a Sitecore Managed Cloud project and for that, I want to patch **AllowedCorsOrigins** node to add **AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2** for adding custom domain of CM site in **Identity Server**.

Since this is a Sitecore Host application so patching should work as explained [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/configuration.html).

When I update file **(root)\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml** directly then everything is working fine as explained [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/15529/1606) but patching is not.

To patch that file I tried following -

I created a patch file as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <IdentityServer>      
      <Clients>
        <DefaultClient>
          <AllowedCorsOrigins>
            <AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>https://cm.mysite.com</AllowedCorsOriginsGroup2>
          </AllowedCorsOrigins>
        </DefaultClient>
      </Clients>
    </IdentityServer>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>
```

and kept it in this location - **sitecoreruntime** > **production** > **Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml**

[image]

but it's not working. I also tried keeping patch file to **sitecoreruntime** > **config** > **production** > **Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml**

[image]

Tried renaming patch file too to z.Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml but no luck.

After every change, I restarted app service.

Sitecore version - 9.1.1

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to view the final/merged configuration of Sitecore Host application something similar to showconfig.aspx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your patch file is at incorrect location, folder structure should be like - 
[image]

in your case error is here - 
[image]

put config folder inside your environment folder, such as **sitecoreruntime > production > config > Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml**

[image]