# Sitecore 9.2 Federated Authentication is not redirecting to https in CM

Tags: federated-authentication

We had configured the Federated authentication for our CM instance.

In the AllowedCorsOriginsGroup we gave two url as **https**://scdev9.local  and **http**://scdev9.local

After authenticating with external provider, the site is redirecting to **http**://scdev9.local/sitecore/login

Our requirement is to redirect to **https**://scdev9.local/sitecore/login

Is there a way to redirect to **https** always

Comment: Can't you configure scdev9.local to only accept https? this way even if you redirect to http://scdev9.local it will switch to https, it's also better for security.

Comment: @AJ, if we configure only https, we are getting unauthorized_client.  hence we added http as per the link https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15528/installing-9-1-xp0-sorry-there-was-an-error-unauthorized-client