# Sitecore 9.3 XP1-CM Post Installation Issue - Sorry there was an error

Tags: installation, identity-server, login

I am installing **Sitecore 9.3 XP1-CM on Windows 2016 Server**. Trying to set up our UAT Servers.

**The installation succeeded** and I can see the login page.

But, if I try to login to the Sitecore Instance, the Identity server is showing **"Sorry, there was an error". (nothing on Unauthorised)**

[image]

**I have everything in place including  with valid URL.** in the **Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml**

[image]

**There are NO logs anything which I can know why this is happening.**

**I have another instance running which was installed using XP0-SingleDeveloper and it is working fine.**

Would appreciate any inputs on this.

Comment: Try to see this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15528/installing-9-1-xp0-sorry-there-was-an-error-unauthorized-client

Comment: Are you using https?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal - Thanks.!! Already saw this link. As I mentioned in the question, every config item is in place. Still not sure why it is not working.

Comment: @MarkCassidy - Yes. It is loading in HTTPS. I am loading the IdentityServer URL directly and it loads in HTTPS as well.